# Magento auto-confirm order instead of admin

Tags: magento

I see my orders in my admin panel and all have status "pending".

Is it possible that the orders are auto-confirmed without the admin having to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom extension for it, you can get help from here.
http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/
Or 
http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is a way to achieve this use the below code and call in from a cron on ur time basis, The code will change the state from pending to processing after 1 hour of placing order.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','pending')
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lt' =>  new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('".now()."', INTERVAL -'60:00' HOUR_MINUTE)")))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')   
    ->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id');
Mage::log("cod diret run from script cron start");
foreach ($orders as $order) {   
    $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();        
    $individualOrder = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    try {
if(!$individualOrder->canInvoice())
{   
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
}
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $individualOrder)->prepareInvoice();
Mage::log("next");
if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
}
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($invoice)
->addObject($invoice->getOrder()); 
$transactionSave->save();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) { 
}
$OrderStatus = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$OrderStatus->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();
    $orderid= $individualOrder->getEntityId();
    $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();     
}
```